# MySQL join table only to find missing values from previous join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Sorry if my title is odd, but I'm not even sure how to word my problem in this description let alone a short title.

We have 1000 users.  400 of them are new.  500 of them have updated their profiles with the new fields we added.  100 have not updated their profiles.

When I try to pull data on a specific field I get 900 results.

```
Select j1.question, j1.response
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 j1 on t1.id_user = j1.iduser AND j1.idquestion IN (26)
```

This is missing the 100 users that haven't updated their profile using the new profile questions.

When I try to pull data on that specific field to include the old profile question that was similar I get 1500 results.

```
Select j1.question, j1.response
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 j1 on t1.id_user = j1.iduser AND (j1.idquestion IN (26) OR j1.idquestion IN (8))
```

This pulls the 900 results from 26 as well as the original 600 users result from 8.

So my question is, how do I only get the data of the idquestion IN (26) and then the 100 left over from idquestion IN (8)?

Comment: `left join` and it would appear as null instead of not appear at all

Comment: IN() OR IN()?!?!?! So what's the point of IN!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(q26.question IS NOT NULL, q26.question, q8.question) as question, IF(q26.response IS NOT NULL, q26.response, q8.response) as response
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as q26
ON 
(t1.id_user = q26.iduser
AND q26.idquestion = 26)
LEFT JOIN table2 as q8
ON
(t1.id_user = q8.iduser
AND q8.idquestion = 8);
```

This should work. Starting with table1 and left joining ensures you get one answer for each user. Joining q26 will join the q26 values if they exist and null otherwise. Joining q8 will do the same in additional columns.

You end up with table1 with some columns that only apply to question26 (or null), followed by columns that only apply to question 8 (or null). Then, if you use IF() in your selects, you can choose the right columns.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the 100 users that where 'missing' in your first query. I am not sure I understand what you want with quesionID(8).

```
         SELECT t1.question, t1.response
           FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 j1 on t1.id_user = j1.iduser 
            AND j1.idquestion IN (26)
          WHERE j1.iduser IS NULL
```

Comment: questionid 26 is "What is your Profession" and questionid 8 is "What is your specialty(old)" So they are two different questions but fit the same demographics section of our report.

Comment: Nice but they would want to change the select into `SELECT t1.id_user`. Otherwise they'll get 100 rows with Nulls.

Comment: @dannycodes, ok, nice. But what exactly do _you_ want as a result now? :) Initially i thought you wanted these 100 "missing"  users, but for that i don't need question 8 (or 72 for that matter) :)

Comment: @oerkelens I need all 1000 entries as the result.  So the 900 with 26 and the 100 with 8 in one query.

Comment: Ok, and in each entry you want the data from questionid 26 _if_ it exists and otherwise from 8? If that is the case i will haev a look at that in a while :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it =)